# Value type equality and strongly named assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

We're developing plugins at our company. In order to test our code better, we have to mock parts of the host application and use that *fake* assembly as a dependency in our tests. Since the original assembly is strongly named we have to disable strong name validation via the Windows registry, otherwise the mocked assembly won't be accepted as a disguise for the original assembly.

Within that assembly there is a type `Point`. I will refer to the original type definition by `Original.Point` and the mocked type by `Mocked.Point`. To be clear, `Mocked.Point` replaces `Original.Point`. Both types have 3 `float` fields for X, Y and Z. `Original.Point` has a few properties and methods that `Mocked.Point` doesn't have, but those shouldn't matter for equality.

Here is the source of `Mocked.Point`:

```
public struct Point
{
    public float X { get; }
    public float Y { get; }
    public float Z { get; }

    public Point3f(float x, float y, float z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
}
```

In our tests, we call a function `Original.Point Host.GePoint()`. `Host` refers to a third assembly from the plugin SDK. That assembly is **not** mocked. We call the function like this:

```
Mocked.Point a = Host.GetPoint();
```

There is no conversion happening here. `Mocked.Point` is our replacement for `Original.Point`. As far as the runtime is concerned, both types are the same.

**Case A**

However if we do an equality comparison between two instances, say

```
Mocked.Point a = Host.GetPoint();
Mocked.Point b = new(1, 0, 0); // b is equivalent to a, no rounding errors or anything
a.Equals(b); // returns false
```

the equality check fails. I verified that `a.GetType() == b.GetType()`.

**Case B**

On the other hand, if we do

```
Mocked.Point a = new(1, 0, 0);
Mocked.Point b = new(1, 0, 0);
a.Equals(b); // returns true
```

the equality check succeeds.

I stepped through the source of `System.ValueType` while debugging `a.Equals(b)`:

```
[SecuritySafeCritical]
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj == null)
    return false;
  RuntimeType type = (RuntimeType) this.GetType();
  if ((RuntimeType) obj.GetType() != type)
    return false;
  object a = (object) this;
  if (ValueType.CanCompareBits((object) this))
    return ValueType.FastEqualsCheck(a, obj); // execution runs to here
  FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
  for (int index = 0; index < fields.Length; ++index)
  {
    object obj1 = ((RtFieldInfo) fields[index]).UnsafeGetValue(a);
    object obj2 = ((RtFieldInfo) fields[index]).UnsafeGetValue(obj);
    if (obj1 == null)
    {
      if (obj2 != null)
        return false;
    }
    else if (!obj1.Equals(obj2))
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and the execution path calls `ValueType.FastEqualsCheck` in the end in **both** cases, which is a compiler intrinsic<s>, so I cannot see what happens there (unless I look at the CLR source)</s>. This call does a `memcmp` on both values ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/07d17b67c168b4b47391b458c909658bcf56ff67/src/coreclr/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L1840) ). This call returns `false` in case A and `true` in case B.

**Question**

Why does (or can) case A fail?

---

I know this a very sketchy scenario but we can't work around this issue in any other way.

Comment: "As far as the runtime is concerned, both types are the same." Have you verified that by checking `a.GetType() == b.GetType()`? My suspicion is that that will return false for the case where equality is failing for you.

Comment: By any chance: Is the OS/Architecture where your 'Host' is running, different then the machine, where you execute the equal check?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes I verified with that exact test. But `ValueType.Equals` should test that in the second `if` right? `if (RuntimeType) obj.GetType() != type`).

Comment: @TheTanic Nope. Both run on the same Windows 10 machine.

Comment: And both programs are 64Bit/32Bit?

Comment: @TheTanic Yep the very same machine.

Comment: @ZdeněkJelínek I verified this manually and both cases run into the `ValueType.FastEqualsCheck` call, which means the CLR considers both types equal. I'm not sure about the physical layout. The struct members have the same layout at least. But I don't know how to check the physical layout.

Comment: If they are a struct, convert them to bytes and compare

Comment: @Timo: Yes, it tests it and will return false if they're not the same - it's returning false, so I thought that was possibly what was happening. It would be good to put in the question that `a.GetType() == b.GetType()` returns true. (I see now what you mean about the execution path, but that wasn't entirely clear to me, and I wouldn't be surprised if debugging through code like this could give misleading results anyway - whereas logging `a.GetType() == b.GetType()` can't mislead.)

Comment: @TheGeneral great idea, check the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue; this is a good one.

I tried to look at the memory that is compared in `ValueType.FastEqualsCheck`, so I marshaled both objects

```
Mocked.Point a = Host.GetPoint();
Mocked.Point b = new(feetToMeter, 0, 0); 

var size = Marshal.SizeOf<Point>();
var memA = new byte[size];
var memB = new byte[size];

unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* pA = memA)
    fixed (byte* pB = memB)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(a, (IntPtr) pA, false);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(b, (IntPtr) pB, false);
    }
}
```

which gives me

```
memA = 48 F9 51 40 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00
memB = 48 F9 51 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Note that `80` in the 5th last place of `memA`? That's part of the second float of the struct (`Point.Y`). I looked up the bit representation of IEEE 754 floats and look at that it's the sign bit. So what happens here is that we compare `-0f == 0f` which in floating point semantic is true, but since these two values have two different binary representations, bitwise comparison fails.

It doesn't help that the debugger swallows the sign when displayed, so `-0f` and `0f` are both displayed as `0`. Furthermore, memberwise comparison is still successful because floating point semantics considers them equal.

This means, that `a.Equals(b)` is false because the runtime uses the fast path via `memcmp`. If it had taken the fallback (which is member wise comparison via reflection), `a.Equals(b)` would've been true.

So in the end it had nothing to do with strong named assemblies. It's only an edge case in the value type equality semantics.

Comment: I had a feeling this would end up in float shenanigans, +1 for the detective work